# Issue regarding the special characters when connecting to sharepoint

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using the asset library tech experience to fetch the list from sharepoint

```
ListService.Lists objLists = new ListService.Lists();
objLists.Credentials = Constant.credentials;
objXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();
objXMLDocument.LoadXml("<QueryOptions><IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><Folder>Tech Experience</Folder><ViewAttributes Scope=\"RecursiveAll\" /></QueryOptions>");
XmlNode objQueryOptions = objXMLDocument.DocumentElement;
resultXml = objLists.GetListItems("Tech Experience", null, null, null, "100", objQueryOptions, null);
```

It throws this error "Error in xml Document" on executing the last line in the given code.

But if I change the asset library in the loadxml(ie from tech Exprience to something else) it works fine.

What I find till now is, the description of items available on this Asset Library contains some special characters like(',",<,>,&) which is creating problem.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

I can not ask my client not to use these characters while uploading new files.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to encode those characters as HTML entity characters:

- '&' as &amp;
- '<' as &lt;
- '>' as &gt;
- ''' as &apos;
- '"' as &quot;